# Which parameter is invalid on a WINCODEC_ERR_INVALIDPARAMETER (System.ArgumentException)

Tags: .net, debugging, wic

I'm debugging a .NET app that uses the WIC wrapper from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/05/03/the-fastest-way-to-resize-images-from-asp-net-and-it-s-more-supported-ish.aspx) and sometimes gets an ArgumentException.  I looked around, that indicates the actual HRESULT was WINCODEC_ERR_INVALIDPARAMETER.  I checked in a debugger, the values seem reasonable, so how do I figure out which one is the problem?  Here's my code:

```
    Public Function CreateThumbnail(ByVal Height As UInteger, ByVal Width As UInteger, Optional ByVal Format As Format = Format.JPG) As Byte()
        'Calculate target dimensions
        Dim TargetDimensions As ThumbnailDimensions = GetThumbnailDimensions(Width, Height)

        'Output stream for the thumbnail to be created on
        Dim OutputStream As New MemoryIStream()

        'Get an appropriate encoder
        Dim Encoder As IWICBitmapEncoder = EncoderByFormat(Format)
        Encoder.Initialize(OutputStream, WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption.WICBitmapEncoderNoCache)

        'Create the output frame with but keep reference to the PropertyBag to add settings later
        Dim OutputFrame As IWICBitmapFrameEncode = Nothing
        Dim arguments As IPropertyBag2() = {Nothing}
        Encoder.CreateNewFrame(OutputFrame, arguments)

        'Add format specific option
        Dim PropertyBag As IPropertyBag2 = arguments(0)

        Select Case Format
            Case Format.JPG
                'Add the 85% quality setting
                Dim ImageQuality As PROPBAG2() = {Nothing}
                ImageQuality(0).pstrName = "ImageQuality"
                PropertyBag.Write(1, ImageQuality, New Object() {0.85F})
        End Select

        'Initialize the OutputFrame with the format specific properties.
        OutputFrame.Initialize(PropertyBag)

        'Set resolution
        OutputFrame.SetResolution(96, 96)

        'Set size
        OutputFrame.SetSize(TargetDimensions.Width, TargetDimensions.Height)

        'Create scaler to actually resize the image
        Dim Scaler = WICFactory.CreateBitmapScaler()
        Scaler.Initialize(InputDecoder.GetFrame(0), TargetDimensions.Width, TargetDimensions.Height, WICBitmapInterpolationMode.WICBitmapInterpolationModeFant)

        'Write the new image to the frame
        Dim Positioner As New WICRect
        Positioner.X = 0 : Positioner.Y = 0 : Positioner.Width = TargetDimensions.Width : Positioner.Height = TargetDimensions.Height


        '''''''''''' EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE!!! '''''''''
        OutputFrame.WriteSource(Scaler, Positioner)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Commit the edits
        OutputFrame.Commit()
        Encoder.Commit()
        Dim OutputBytes As Byte() = OutputStream.ToArray()
        OutputStream.Close()

        'Return the bytes of the thumbnail
        Return OutputBytes
End Function
```